# Triangulated categories with a finite number of compact generators admit a single generator

Tags: triangulated-categories

I was reading an old question on Mathoverflow about examples of compactly generated triangulated categories which do not admit a single generator.
My first idea was to consider the homotopy category of orthogonal $G$-spectra: here  the sphere spectrum detects only $\pi^G_*$ but not $\pi^H_*$ for all $H$ subgroups of $G$, you need to consider the hom sets from all the $\Sigma^{\infty}_{+}G/H$ to get the $\underline{\pi}_*$ of a spectrum. But then I realized that I can just take the coproduct of these suspension spectra and since $[\bigvee_i A_i, -]_*\cong \bigoplus_i[A_i,-]_*$ for a finite indexing set $I$ the wedge $\bigvee_{H \leq G}\Sigma^{\infty}_{+}G/H$ should be a compact generator when $G$ is a finite group.

This is the concrete example I had in mind, but the idea can easily be generalized: if the compactly generated triangulated category $T$ admits a finite set of generators $\{g_i\}_i$ then is $\oplus_i g_i$ a single compact generator of $T$? This seems really odd and I think there is a silly mistake in my argument which I am not seeing.

Comment: That's correct. Why does it seem really odd?

Comment: I thought that the number of generators was a bit more rigid: I mean I am not claiming it is an invariant in any sort of way but basically this means a triangulated category either has only one generator or it has infinite generators. Then I could understand that we are not considering the sum of the generators since each of them is easier to understand separately and they form some sort of building blocks for the triangulated category.